# analysis of a dodecic polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Consider the polynomial
$$
\Phi(\omega):=\psi_6\omega^{12}+\psi_5\omega^{10}+\psi_4\omega^8+\psi_3\omega^6+\psi_2\omega^4+\psi_1\omega^2+\psi_0=0,
$$
where $\psi_k$, $k=0,\ldots,6$ are real coefficients, and $\psi_0<0$. It's easy to show that the polynomial has at least one positive real root. I would like to constrain the polynomial so that one is guaranteed the existence and uniqueness of a positive real solution, $\omega^{\ast}>0$. Further to this, I would like to analytically solve the equation for the $\omega^{\ast}>0$. Any ideas are welcome, especially references to relevant literature.